# why stop word removal be null? (php)

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, nlp, text-processing

I'm the beginner NLP programmer in PHP.
I just want to discuss about the stop word removal.

this is my practice:

I have the following declaration of a variable `$words = "he's the young man";`

and then I remove the common words like this

```
 $common_words = $this->common_words();
 $ncwords = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$common_words).')\b/','',$data); 
 // I have save the array common_words in another function
```

and I explode my no common words

```
$a_ncwords=explode(" ", $ncwords);
```

But, when I print `$a_ncwords`, like so `print_r($a_ncwords);`

I get a result like this:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => young [3] => man )
```

why are the `index[0]` and `index[1]` array values null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the empty array elements.

To appease those who said it didn't answer your question:

Your preg_replace is replacing words with null and when you explode because your regex is off, those null values are getting created in your array `$a_ncwords` when you `explode`.

```
$a_ncwords = array_filter($a_ncwords);
```

Comment: I have tried it. This simple code solved my problem. :)
Thanks sir.

Comment: Surely this (and the other answer) doesn't answer the question: *why are the `index[0]` and `index[1]` array values null?*

Comment: the other answer solved my problem too, but I need the basic code sir. thanks for your respond. I've vote the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are replacing the words with an empty string. The array elements still exist, they are just empty now.

You should remove them from the array if they are empty. You can do this like so:

```
array_filter($ncwords, function($item) { return !is_null($item); });
```

Comment: What's the difference between using callback function vs not? Genuinely curious

Comment: If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE will be removed.   I added a callback for example sake.

Comment: Without the callback, "falsey" values would be removed from the array (e.g. `false`, `""`, `NULL`, `0`).  With this callback, only `NULL` values are removed. In this case, it doesn't matter much.